# How to countdown to a date in java?

Tags: java, date, time

So i am creating an application to countdown to a date in java.

So lets say i parse these 2 days:

> Date Now = 2016/01/15 16:52:22
>   Date End = 2016/01/15 18:37:18

How would i calculate the differences so that i can get the output like so:

> 1 hour, 44 minutes and 56 seconds

instead of the total hours, total minutes and total seconds.

I guess the best way to explain it is that i need to get the seconds left of the minute, the minutes left of the hour, etc, etc.

Comment: That depends on how you're storing your dates.  Are you using `java.util.Date`? `java.time.LocalDateTime`?  joda time?

Comment: @azurefrog I am using java.util.Date and using SimpleDateFormater to format it.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1555262/calculating-the-difference-between-two-java-date-instances

Comment: How exactly is `1 hour, 44 minutes and 56 seconds` different from `total hours, total minutes and total seconds`?

Comment: @JimGarrison Because instead of the total seconds being every second between the start and end date, i need it to be the number of seconds left of the current minute.

Answer (score 1):

You haven't specify your date format. Supposed you use the `Date` class, the following code gives you a difference in milliseconds.

```
long difference = dateEnd.getTime() - dateNow.getTime();
```

Then you approach to your result with a simple calculation:

```
int seconds = (int) (difference / 1000) % 60 ;
int minutes = (int) ((difference / (1000*60)) % 60);
int hours   = (int) ((difference / (1000*60*60)) % 24);
```